# Usuário "comunidade" é necromante?

Tags: debate

Nas últimas semanas, percebi que tópicos antigos aparecem "do nada" na home do site.

Exemplo de tópico: [Problema com concatenação de variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49468/problema-com-concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-vari%C3%A1vel)

Assim como a maioria, eu costumo passar o olho nos tópicos da home, quando tem algo de interesse ou fácil de responder, para ganhar pontos fáceis, eu entro e tento a sorte.. hehe

Ok, falando sério, percebi que esses tópicos antigos, os quais não possuem nenhum conteúdo novo, aparecem com assinatura do membro "Comunidade".

Veja o screenshot: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu mesmo não lembrava que eu tinha participado desse tópico, meses atrás.
Li a pergunta e vi as respostas e lembrei. Olhei as datas, todas de meses atrás. Então procurei se tinha algum comentário ou resposta nova mas, não tem.

Então, a pergunta aqui é, por que esses tópicos, sem conteúdo novo, aparecem no destaque da home?

O nosso amigo "Comunidade" quer receber a pá dourada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que 'comunidade' edita a pergunta para colocar em destaque, para ver se aparece alguma resposta nova que atenda a pergunta, se olhar bem as perguntas que normalmente aparecessem são aquelas sem a resposta aceita.

Comment: Também achei isso. Acho que é automatizado.