# Responder uma pergunta antiga "ressuscitada" pelo bot Comunidade passou a ser errado?

Tags: suporte, respostas

Por muitas vezes vejo tópicos antigos voltando a página inicial pelo bot [Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade), entretanto quando alguém responde a uma pergunta dessa, pois as respostas lá não são boas ou por conta do lapso de tempo a resposta pode ter mudado, são denunciadas por "Respostas tardias" e recebem downvote por isso.

Buscando em alguns tópicos, vi um [moderador](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4241/usu%C3%A1rio-comunidade-%C3%A9-necromante#comment12150_4241) dando a entender que não há problema em responder perguntas caso as respostas anteriores não tenham sido satisfatórias.

Também existe esse outro [tópico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4576/responder-perguntas-antigas-por%C3%A9m-sem-respostas), incentivando a responder caso necessário.

Porém esse [outro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2155/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-antigas-abandonadas) da a entender que elas deveriam ser ignoradas. E com isso, existem diversas opiniões contraditórias e que de fato causam punições.

Diante disso, eu pergunto aos moderadores e especialistas atuais.

Não é permitido responder perguntas antigas trazidas de volta pelo bot Comunidade?

A regra "Respostas tardias" é interpretativa dependendo do moderador?

O fato do site ter uma medalha para quem responde a uma pergunta antiga não conflita com essa regra?

Comment: Se a pergunta estiver aberta e souber a resposta, responda. A orientação que viu para ignorar determinadas perguntas é especifica para a moderação das perguntas e não para autoria de respostas.

Comment: Só pra constar que "Respostas Tardias" é uma [fila de análise](/review/late-answers), e o sistema **automaticamente** coloca lá as respostas feitas em perguntas antigas (não tem "denúncia"). E os votos negativos não são dados porque elas são tardias, e sim porque são ruins mesmo. **Esse é - ou pelo menos deveria ser - o critério, independente da pergunta ser nova ou antiga**. Eu já respondi perguntas antigas (algumas vários anos depois, inclusive) e não há problema nenhum nisso (e várias respostas foram positivadas e algumas até aceitas, pois o que conta é a qualidade, não a idade)

Comment: Mas então deveriam ser só "respostas de baixa qualidade", e não "respostas tardias", ou os dois? @hkotsubo

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Se foi sobre o nome da fila, "Respostas Tardias" é porque são respostas dadas em perguntas antigas (não dá pra saber se são de baixa qualidade, então primeiro elas vão pra fila e lá a gente analisa).

Answer (score 4):

Não é errado. Responder qualquer boa pergunta no site continua certo.